# PHP parse string to multiple array

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
$str= "array((1, '31/10/2014 23:01:19', '5476743', 'name1', '89298.08', '679155', '5.895.804.754', '240', '679155', '5.895.804.754', '240')(1, '31/10/2014 23:01:29', '3724881', 'name2', '54141.48', '115663', '202.718.140', '20', '115663', '202.718.140', '20'));"
```

Is possible that the array has more elements. I want to parse to get something like this:

```
$array[0] = array(1, '31/10/2014 23:01:19', '5476743', 'name1', '89298.08', '679155', '5.895.804.754', '240', '679155', '5.895.804.754', '240'); 
$array[1] = array(1, '31/10/2014 23:01:29', '3724881', 'name2', '54141.48', '115663', '202.718.140', '20', '115663', '202.718.140', '20');
```

somebody can help me?
Thanks

Comment: how did you get this string?

Comment: It's the return from an api call

Comment: It is unclear if each element in your result array should be strings or arrays.

Comment: @M.Page each element have to be an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API is trying to return php code I suppose but it is incorrect. If you could alter your API to return valid php syntax and you trust it is not going to send you malicious data, it is very easy:

```
$str= "array(array(1, '31/10/2014 23:01:19', '5476743', 'name1', '89298.08', '679155', '5.895.804.754', '240', '679155', '5.895.804.754', '240'),array(1, '31/10/2014 23:01:29', '3724881', 'name2', '54141.48', '115663', '202.718.140', '20', '115663', '202.718.140', '20'));";
$array = eval('return ' . $str);

print_r($array);
```

## EDIT:

If you are able to alter your API code, a very easy way to return valid php code is `var_export()`

Comment: I'll ask to the api creator to try it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function doit($str){
        $str=substr($str, 6,strlen($str)-8);
        $array1=explode(")(",')'.$str.'(');
        $count=0;
        foreach ($array1 as $key => $str1) {
            if(empty(trim($str1))){
                continue;
        }
        $str2=substr($str1, 1,strlen($str1)-1);
        $array2=explode(',', $str2);
        foreach ($array2 as $key1 => $one) {
            $tone=trim($one);
            if(empty($tone))continue;
            if(substr($tone, 0,1)=="'" && substr($tone, strlen($tone)-1,1)=="'"){
                $tone=substr($tone, 1,strlen($tone)-2);
            }
            $array3[$count][$key1]=$tone;
        }
        $count++;
    }
    return $array3;
}
```

result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [1] => 31/10/2014 23:01:19
        [2] => 5476743
        [3] => name1
        [4] => 89298.08
        [5] => 679155
        [6] => 5.895.804.754
        [7] => 240
        [8] => 679155
        [9] => 5.895.804.754
        [10] => 240
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 31/10/2014 23:01:29
        [2] => 3724881
        [3] => name2
        [4] => 54141.48
        [5] => 115663
        [6] => 202.718.140
        [7] => 20
        [8] => 115663
        [9] => 202.718.140
        [10] => 20
    )

)
```

Comment: Don't know why but function fails for me when the code enter in the foreach statement

Answer (score 0):

Here I propose a code that doesn't rely on evil eval and won't fail on values containing commas or backslashes.

```
function _strpos_first_of_set($chrset,&$str,$offset)
{
    $pos = PHP_INT_MAX ;
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($chrset);$i++)
    {   
        $p = @strpos($str,$chrset{$i},$offset);
        if($p!==false)
            $pos=min($pos,$p);
    }
    return ($pos==PHP_INT_MAX ) ? false : $pos;
}

function doit(&$str)
{
    $offset = 6 ;/*array(*/
    $array = array();
    $ai = -1;
    $aj = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        $p = @strpos($str,"(",$offset);
        if($p===false)
            return $array;
        $offset=$p+1;
        $array[++$ai] = array();
        $aj=0;
        for(;;)
        {
            $p = _strpos_first_of_set("',)",$str,$offset);
            if($p===false)
                return false;
            if($str{$p}==")")
            {
                $offset=$p+1;
                break;
            }
            if($str{$p}==",")
            {
                $array[$ai][$aj++] = trim(substr($str,$offset,$p-$offset));
                $offset = $p+1;
            }
            else
            {
                $offset=++$p;
                for(;;)
                {
                    $p = _strpos_first_of_set("'\\",$str,$p);
                    if($p===false)
                        return false;
                    if($str{$p}=="\\")
                        $p += 2;
                    else
                    {
                        $array[$ai][$aj++] = stripslashes(substr($str,$offset,$p-$offset));
                        $p = _strpos_first_of_set(",)",$str,$p+1);
                        if($p===false)
                            return false;
                        $offset = ($str{$p} == ",") ? $p+1 : $p ;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```